sudo apt --fix-broken install does not work, and I get an error about apport MaxReports

I've tried to install some drivers for my machine as there was an error in Minecraft I'm having that could be related to drivers.
I have tried to install a few things, however, I get the same error everytime: 
```No apport report written because MaxReports has already been reached
                                                                    Errors were 
encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/libglx0_1.7.0-2101~22.04_i386.deb
 /var/cache/apt/archives/libgl1_1.7.0-2101~22.04_amd64.deb
 /var/cache/apt/archives/libegl1_1.7.0-2101~22.04_i386.deb
 /var/cache/apt/archives/libopengl0_1.7.0-2101~22.04_i386.deb
 /var/cache/apt/archives/libglvnd0_1.7.0-2101~22.04_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```
And, above it,
```
No apport report written because MaxReports has already been reached
```
Can anyone help me?
Specs:
Ubuntu 22.04 LTS
Intel UHD Graphics 600
4GB Ram 
(just shout if you need any more specs)
Tried this:

sudo dpkg -i --force-overwrite /var/cache/apt/archives/libglx0_1.7.0-2101~22.04_i386.deb
And got this error:
(Reading database ... 217521 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../libglx0_1.7.0-2101~22.04_i386.deb ...
Unpacking libglx0:i386 (1.7.0-2101~22.04) over (1.4.0-1) ...
dpkg: warning: overriding problem because --force enabled:
dpkg: warning: trying to overwrite shared '/usr/share/doc/libglx0/changelog.Debian.gz', which is different from other instances of package libglx0:i386
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libglx0:i386:
 libglx0:i386 depends on libglvnd0 (= 1.7.0-2101~22.04); however:
  Package libglvnd0:i386 is not configured yet.
 libglx0:i386 depends on libglx-mesa0; however:
  Package libglx-mesa0:i386 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package libglx0:i386 (--install):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.35-0ubuntu3.6) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 libglx0:i386

